# MONACA RSSリーダーがRSSを読み込まない

Tags: monaca

サンプルの RSSリーダーをそのまま起動しても loading.gif が表示され続けるか、 
Failed to load RSS みたいなのが表示されるだけです。

該当のサンプルは 現在使用できないのでしょうか？ 
れとも 私の環境 利用の仕方が間違っていおるのでしょうか？

ご回答をお待ちしております。

Answer (score 0):

monaca開発画面のpreviewではloading.gifが表示されるのみですが、デバッガーではちゃんと表示されましたよ。お試しくださいませ。

Answer (score 0):

私も同じ現象だったので以下のURLを参考に機能を付けたしていったところ、ある場所で同じ現象になりました。
http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/tutorial/monaca_rssreader.html#/JavaScript

ためしにURLを元に戻したら正常に表示されました。

```
// CHANGE YOUR URL HERE!
 var feedUrl = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml";
// フィードのURLを変更してください
//var feedUrl = "http://blog.mb.cloud.nifty.com/?feed=rss2";
```

理由はわかりませんがrssの形式が意図されないものだったのでしょうか。